# How to center text below an image label?

Tags: html, css

So essentially I am attempting to get the label text to display under the label image, instead of to the right of it. But it appears as though when I try doing so via CSS, it breaks the layout of my page. I feel like I'm overthinking things haha! what am I doing incorrectly?

screenshot attached - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU2IA.png

heres the CSS:

```
input[type=radio] {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    line-height: normal;
    border: none;
label {
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
 display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
}
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="ram" value="Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 Memory (+$0.00)" id="ram1-radio" onClick="Changeram(this.value);" checked >
    
<label for="ram1-radio"><img src="https://voidtechpcs.com/libs/images/layout/corsairvengeanceram.jpg" width="30%"> (+$0)</label>

<input type="radio" name="ram" value="Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 Memory (+$0.00)" id="ram2-radio" onClick="Changeram(this.value);">

<label for="ram2-radio"><img src="https://voidtechpcs.com/libs/images/layout/corsairvengeancergb.jpg" width="30%">(+$0)</label>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<input type="radio" name="ram" value="Corsair Vengeance LPX 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4-3600 Memory (+$0.00)" id="ram3-radio" onClick="Changeram(this.value);">

<label for="ram3-radio"><img src="https://voidtechpcs.com/libs/images/layout/corsairvengeanceram.jpg" width="30%">(+$0)</label>

<input type="radio" name="ram" value="Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4-3600 Memory (+$0.00)" id="ram4-radio" onClick="Changeram(this.value);">

<label for="ram4-radio"><img src="https://voidtechpcs.com/libs/images/layout/corsairvengeancergb.jpg" width="30%">(+$0)</label>

</p>
```

Using these CSS styles as you said worked flawlessly i made a stylelabel class to wrap it together just as you also said. The images and radio boxes now display correctly, and are now 2x2 display :D

```
.stylelabel label {
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
}
.stylelabel label img {
    border: none;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the CSS?

Comment: I just popped it into the post

Comment: `label img { display: block; }` ...?

Comment: it got it under the image label, buuuut it broke everything else lol. It should be side by side, two image labels side by side, then the next two under that should also be side by side. but its all in a giant line D:

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/svwrBPV.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `<br />` between image and text, use also `text-align:center;` in the label selector, keeping inline-block display but not twice, it's useless.

Comment: This doesn't work :/ That was the first thing I tried haha

<input type="radio" name="ram" value="Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 Memory (+$0.00)" id="ram1-radio" onClick="Changeram(this.value);" checked >
<label for="ram1-radio"><img src="https://voidtechpcs.com/libs/images/layout/cosairvengeanceram.jpg" width="35%"> <br />(+$0)</label>

Comment: you clearly must have a typo anywhere, it works here...

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well. It's in a class that should keep them side by side, buuuuut it isnt.

Comment: try setting a width and height equally for all labels by css

Comment: heres a screencast of what I mean, I remove display:block; from label img, label, or image and it puts everything in one single row instead of side by side https://watch.screencastify.com/v/1mS0Fh95FCFDp0rY3Jt3

Comment: it's normal, the default display for label will then be inline. so the width will be inherited from parent

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, I havent touched html or CSS in years. how would I go about getting it to be the right width? I set label width to the container width and that also does nothing lol

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9w8y14xo/

Comment: width and height must be set by inline style, or inside a selector on a stylesheet or a <style></style> tag

Comment: Thank you so much! That's the one thing I didn't do because I'm stupid LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Remove display: inline-block from the label but if that does not work try put the input and label into one div then in the css target the div and give it

```
display: flex
flex-direction: column
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).